# How to parse wrong data in a column then save to other table using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to parse the correct date data then separate or transfer the wrong date data in a separated table.

Example:

Correct Table A

```
ColumnId, ColumnDate
1, 06/11/2016
2, 簽訂臨時買賣合約後 交易再未有進展 The PASP has not proceeded further
3, 11/11/2016
4, 在 7/12/2016 ，基 於法例35(2)(b)條所 容許的原因，售價 更改為
5, 24-10-2016
```

Wrong Table B

```
ColumnId, ColumnDate
2, 簽訂臨時買賣合約後 交易再未有進展 The PASP has not proceeded further
4, 在 7/12/2016 ，基 於法例35(2)(b)條所 容許的原因，售價 更改為
```

Comment: Use `TRY_CONVERT(DATE, ColumnDate, X)` (where X is 101 if your dates are mm/dd/yyyy and 103 if X is dd/mm/yyyy). You'll get NULL values for any that fail to convert to a date, so your wrong table would be filled with those where the try_convert is null.

Comment: Question is unclear.  What would be your desired result?

Comment: So `ColumnDate` is a string rather than a date as it should be, and you want to find every string that doesn't represent a date in the formats dd-mm-yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy?